# find emitting unexpected ".", making wc -l list more contents than expected

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, find

I'm trying to use the newer command as follows:

```
touch $HOME/mark.start -d "$d1"
touch $HOME/mark.end -d "$d2"
SF=$HOME/mark.start
EF=$HOME/mark.end
find . -newer $SF ! -newer $EF
```

But this gives me an output like this:

```
.
./File5
```

and counts it as 2 files, however that directory only has 1 file i.e., File5. Why is this happening and how to solve it?

**UPDATE**:

I'm actually trying to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
check_dir () {
  d1=$2
  d2=$((d1+1))
  f1=`mktemp`
  f2=`mktemp`
  touch -d $d1 $f1
  touch -d $d2 $f2
  n=$(find $1 \( -name "*$d1*" \) -o \( -newer $f1 ! -newer $f2 \) | wc -l)
  if [ $n != $3 ]; then echo $1 "=" $n ; fi
  rm -f $f1 $f2
}
```

That checks if the directory has file that either has a particular date in the format YYYMMDD or if its last modification time was last 1 day.

```
check_dir ./dir1 20151215 4
check_dir ./dir2 20151215 3
```

where in dir1 there should be 4 such files and if it is not true then it will print the actual number of files that is there.

So, when the directory only has file with dates in their name, then it checks them fine, but when it checks with newer, it always gives 1 file extra (which is not even there in the directory). Why is this happening???

Comment: This is a very good start towards a test case. Perhaps you might set d1 and d2 values, and create a file somewhere between them to have a fully standalone reproducer? (And maybe create contents somewhere other than $HOME for easier cleanup?)

Comment: Also, unrelated to your actual problem, there are a bunch of quoting bugs here; see http://shellcheck.net/ for automated detection of same.

Comment: Also, there's a bunch of nonportable usage here, so not everyone will be able to run your tests. For instance, not all versions of `touch` allow options to follow positional arguments -- the POSIX standard only requires `touch` to work if the options come first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated the question with what my real problem is. I was just trying to figure out why that's happening. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Ahh! Use `-mindepth 1` to exempt the directory itself.

Comment: ...btw, you still have a whole lotta bugs related to inadequate quotes. Please run your script through http://shellcheck.net/ and update the question accordingly.

Comment: Also, if you're using GNU find, you can make all this *much* more efficient by passing the date strings around without creating temporary files at all; see `-newerXY`, particularly with `Y` specified as `t`.

Comment: BTW, claiming that `.` is not there in the directory is false. `.` is a special name that's **always** there in every directory; it's the inode of the directory object on the filesystem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks why there's an extra `.` in the results from `find`, even when no file or directory by that name exists. The answer is simple: `.` **always** exists, even when it's hidden. Use `ls -a` to show hidden contents, and you'll see that it's present.

---

Your existing `find` command doesn't exempt the target directory itself -- `.` -- from being a legitimate result, which is why you're getting more results than you expect.

Add the following filter:

```
-mindepth 1  # only include content **under** the file or directory specified
```

...or, if you only want to count *files*, use...

```
-type f      # only include regular files
```

---

Assuming GNU find, by the way, this all can be made far more efficient:

```
check_dir() {
  local d1 d2 # otherwise these variables leak into global scope
  d1=$2
  d2=$(gdate -d "+ 1 day $d1" '+%Y%m%d') # assuming GNU date is installed as gdate
  n=$(find "$1" -mindepth 1 \
                -name "*${d1}*" -o \
                '(' -newermt "$d1" '!' -newermt "$d2" ')' \
                -printf '\n' | wc -l)
  if (( n != $3 )); then
    echo "$1 = $n"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Oh! I have already tried that, but unfortunately, my find doesn't support newermt. :(

Comment: There's a reason I made that only an addendum to my answer as opposed to the whole thing.

Comment: BTW, if you don't need to recurse, is there a reason you're using `find` *at all*, as opposed to just doing the logic natively in bash?

Comment: Yes, I need to check the files which either have a particular date in their filename or were last modified in last 1 day in all the directories.

Comment: BTW, could I ask you one more thing. d2=$((d1 + 1)) that I'm doing, calculates the next day's date, but for end of month dates like 20151231, this won't work. How you I add that exception?

Comment: That's easy if you have GNU date, but since you're on a platform without GNU tools, I suggest asking that as its own question (in the unlikely event that it isn't already asked and answered).

Comment: ...that said, I've updated to show the easy (GNU date) solution.